# Particle system splitting in half

Tags: particles

the noob I am recently tried to make a tree, and to make the branches, I decided to make a particle system with my leaves on my branch mesh. But I noticed that some of the leaves were floating out of the mesh. After playing around with the particle settings (enabling rotation, setting inittial rotation to global z and phase to -0.480) I realised that the disposition of the floating leaves was absolutely not random, but in fact a duplicate of the shape of my branch :[image]

But I don't know what I'm supposed to do to correct that.
Any help would be very appreciated :)

Here is my [blender file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K4yH-E2TVO6HSDLnrgLddYpzrxutVMSK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your leaves origin to last of petiole, and set inittial rotation to **Velocity/Hair**. It might help